# Dynamically Changing a ListView (by day)

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, django-generic-views

I have a `ListView` (generic CBV) of events. This `ListView` should dynamically update each day, so that "old" events (i.e. events that have already happened) are excluded from the `context` when a user visits the page.

I just noticed that this page is not actually behaving as expected (a server restart is required in order for the `ListView` to update). I have a suspicion that this is because I'm using the `queryset` method, and that I should be doing the processing earlier:

```
class EventDirectoryView(ListView):
    model = Event
    # Exclude objects that are expired
    queryset = Event.objects.exclude(deadline__lt=(date.today()-timedelta(1)))
    template_name = 'event-directory.html'
```

In order to achieve my desired outcome, what is the earliest I should be modifying the queryset so that it is run each time the page is loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override the [`get_queryset()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset) method:

```
class EventDirectoryView(ListView):
    ...
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Event.objects.exclude(deadline__lt=(date.today()-timedelta(1)))
```

Comment: Doesn't the `queryset` I have specified in my class get [passed to get_queryset()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_queryset)?

Comment: Yes, by default `get_queryset()` returns the `queryset` attribute but you don't need the default behaviour.  You need to create new queryset for each request instead of using the same queryset for all requests.  That is why you have to override this method.

Comment: Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/list.py#L26) helped clear this up. Essentially, `queryset` is defined once. If I use the default `get_queryset()` method, without overriding it, the original `queryset` value is used. This `queryset` value is determined the first time the view is requested, and it isn't "re-calculated" after that point. That's why `get_queryset()` needs to be overridden. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Follow up: Is it redundant to have a `model` and `queryset` defined? It seems like the `model` is only used if there is no `queryset` defined. Is this correct?

Comment: I am not sure but I think yes, you can omit the `model` in case of defined `queryset`.